# Angular Ionic - Directive not reloading on view change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Since ionic has caching of views, how do I reload a particular directive on view load. I don't want to use `cache: false` and reload the entire view. I tried the following in the controller function of the directive definition object.

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", function () {
     // logic
  });
})
```

But the controller function of the directive itself is not loading because of ionic view caching.

How can I make a directive to reload on view change in ionic.

Answer (score 0):

In your directive, use data from your ionic view and in the `$ionicview.enter` function just reload the data the directive displays.

like e.g.

```
restrict: 'E',
scope: true,
bindToController: true,
controller: function ($scope, $element) { ... }
```

Comment: Can you provide a working demo? This doesn't work for me. When I reload the page the data is reloaded in `ionicView.enter` but the directive's `link` function isn't called